# Kotlin and Upper Type Bounds with Covariance

Tags: kotlin

Does Kotlin support upper / lower type bounds in a covariance setting. Eg, I want to say

```
class Foo<out T> {
  fun or<U of T or greater>(other: U): <U> = ...
}
```

which in Scala would be

```
class Foo[+T] {
  def or[U >: T](other: U): U = ...
}
```

But the compiler doesn't seem to like this, it complains about the covarianceness of the type parameter T.

Answer (score 11):

Kotlin does not support lower bounds at this point. Sometimes you can get away with defining an extension function instead of a member:

```
fun <T> Foo<T>.or(other: T): T = ...
```

Comment: And upper bounds not supported with covariance?

Comment: Upper bounds are unsound for covariance, thus not allowed

Comment: How so, in the context of the example I gave that is common throughout Scala's SDK?

Comment: The example I gave is a lower bound.

Comment: @AndreyBreslav In Scala, `Option[+A]` has a method `getOrElse(other: => B): B` where `B >: A`. Why is this considered safe, considering that `B` could be an `A`, but not when the lower bound is removed? Moreover, are there plans to add lower type bounds to Kotlin to enable such methods? Any type constructor in Kotlin is currently doomed to either define its type parameter as covariant and forfeit methods such as the one above, or forfeit covariance, which prevents one from writing ADTs that have "empty" instances (Tree, Option, etc., since they won't compile when instantiated with `Nothing`)

Comment: @Matthias "Moreover, are there plans to add lower type bounds to Kotlin to enable such methods?" — it's on the table, yes